# How to combine two arrow function?

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

how to combine below two functions , which I need to use in  single element. Please help

```
onClick={() => setSelectedItem("List A")}
onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}

e.g <a onClick={function1, funtion2}
```

Comment: Like this `onClick={() => { function1(); funtion2() }}`?

Comment: you can have more than 1 statement in an arrow function, just use curly brackets to enclose the body of the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
onClick = {(e) => { setSelectedItem("List A"); e.stopPropagation() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

invoke them all in one function body

```
<a onClick={(e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  setSelectedItem("List A")
}} >
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put them into a single function

```
onClick = {(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setSelectedItem("List A");
}}
```